# crashes in Xcode version 4.2 and iOS 5(released oct-12, 2011) at [self.tableview reload data]

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

i was implementing the table view programmatically, where i set property of mSelectedSubUnitIndex of (NSIndexPath) type as non atomic and retain and synthesized in .m . When i load my tableviewcontroller then method:

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath
:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
CGFloat height = 0.0;
    SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *subUnitExercises = [self sortArray:[subUnit.subUnitExercise allObjects]];
  NSLog(@"mSelectedSubUnitIndex.row........%d",mSelectedSubUnitIndex.row);
NSLog(@"subUnitExercises........%d",[subUnitExercises count]);
  if (indexPath.row == mSelectedSubUnitIndex.row && [subUnitExercises count]>1) {
    height =CELL_EXPAND_HEIGHT ;
}
else {
    height = CELL_NORMAL_HEIGHT;
}
return height;   
}
```

run quite fine. When i return back to my tableviewcontoller from other controller then it crashes(object message send) at same method on line number 5 at NSLog, and give exception at method at `[self.tableView reloadData];. It is resolved by commenting`[self.tableView reloadData];.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
DebugLog(@"start");
    //[self.tableview reloadData];

execountarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int k=0;k<[mSubUnitsArray count];k++)
{
    SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:k];
    NSArray *subUnitExercises = [subUnit.subUnitExercise allObjects];
    [execountarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[subUnitExercises  
    count]]];
}

///////////////
if (managedObjectContext){

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
entityForName:@"TSubUnitExerciseProgress" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Order the events by creation date, most recent first.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
  initWithKey:@"editDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, 
    nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    // Execute the fetch -- create a mutable copy of the result.
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext 
    executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
        myNotes = nil;
        [myNotes removeAllObjects]; 
    }
    else
    {
        [myNotes setArray: mutableFetchResults];
    }



    //NSLog(@"My notes count:--------unitviewcontroller--------------->%d", 
      [myNotes count]);
    if([myNotes count] ==0)
    {
    setExer1Done:NO;
    setExer2Done:NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"hey :P");

    }

}
//  [self.tableview reloadData];  

}
```

didSelectRowAtIndex

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath 
{
DebugLog(@" -start- \n");
mSelectedSubUnitIndex = indexPath;
SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *subUnitExercises = [self sortArray:[subUnit.subUnitExercise allObjects]];
if([subUnitExercises count]!=1) 
{
    NSArray* paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:  
[mSelectedSubUnitIndex row] inSection:0]];
    [tableview beginUpdates];
    [tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths   
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths  
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableview endUpdates];
}
else
{
    //SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:  
[mSelectedSubUnitIndex row]];
    SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *subUnitExercises = [self sortArray:[subUnit.subUnitExercise 
 allObjects]];
    if ([subUnitExercises count] > 0) {
        SubUnitExercise *subUnitExercise = [subUnitExercises 
 objectAtIndex:0];
        [self loadSubUnitExercise:subUnitExercise];
    }
}
  }
```

this is running on iOS 4 but when i build through Xcode version 4.2 and iOS 5 (released oct-12, 2011) then it crashes. Can't figure out the problem. help me out!!

cellForRowAtIndex method

now i am getting exception at if-statement at mSelectedsubunitindex.row when i scroll, but i resolved only checking that if (indexPath.row){},  and also row remain selected when i return bad to my tableview controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:
 (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {    
DebugLog(@"-start- \n");
SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *subUnitExercises = [self sortArray:[subUnit.subUnitExercise allObjects]];
NSString *str1 = [[subUnit performSelector:@selector(title)]copy];
if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"1. was/were"]) 
{
    global = str1;
}
//if(indexPath.row==mSelectedSubUnitIndex.row)
if(indexPath.row)
    {

    if ([subUnitExercises count] != 1)
    {
      SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:            
      [mSelectedSubUnitIndex row]];
        NSArray *subUnitExercises = [self sortArray:
        [subUnit.subUnitExercise allObjects]];
        SubUnitCell *subUnitcell = (SubUnitCell*) cell;

        mCellSubTopicLabel.text = subUnit.title;

        if([myNotes count] == 0)
        {
            NSNumber *isDone = [[subUnitExercises objectAtIndex:1] isDone];

            [subUnitcell setExer2Done:NO];
            mExer2Checkbox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[isDone boolValue]?   
            kExerciseCheckmark :kExerciseWrongmark];

            isDone = [[subUnitExercises objectAtIndex:0] isDone];
            [subUnitcell setExer1Done:NO];
            mExer1Checkbox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[isDone boolValue]?
             kExerciseCheckmark :kExerciseWrongmark];

        }
        else 
        {
            NSNumber *isDone = [[subUnitExercises objectAtIndex:1] isDone];

            [subUnitcell setExer2Done:[isDone boolValue]];
            mExer2Checkbox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[isDone boolValue]?
            kExerciseCheckmark :kExerciseWrongmark];
            isDone = [[subUnitExercises objectAtIndex:0] isDone];
            [subUnitcell setExer1Done:[isDone boolValue]];
            mExer1Checkbox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[isDone boolValue]?
            kExerciseCheckmark :kExerciseWrongmark];        
        }
        [subUnitcell.contentView addSubview:mCellSubTopicContentView];

}

}
```

Comment: What sort of crash? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @RoboticCat: yes off course! but all this code is running in iOS 4 and 3 also

Comment: Can you also post the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?  Also the stack trace isn't helping - can you add the symbolicated crash log?

Comment: @RoboticCat: ok i am posting the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason NSIndexPath assignment (`=`) and equality(`==`) is not working in IOS5. I have solved the problem using `self` before any `NSIndexPath` object e.g.

```
self.mSelectedSubUnitIndex
```

There is another way solving this assignment  using copy like this:

```
anIndexPath = (NSIndexPath*) [anotherIndexPath  copy];
```

Equality works in same way. Like:

```
if([self.mSelectedSubUnitIndex isEqual:anotherIndexPath])
{

}
```

Comment: thanks for helping!! i used if([self.mSelectedSubUnitIndex isEqual:anotherIndexPath]) and crash get resolved

Comment: You should retain the index path - the "self.---" takes care of this if the property is marked "retain". Otherwise (or if not a property) you should retain/release yourself

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick once over of your code.  Two things jump out at me:

1: The very last line of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` calls `[self.tableview reloadData]`.

This is unnecessary as the returned cell will be displayed as you have just configured it.  It would also seem that this would cause a drawing loop ("reloadData->cellForRowAtIndexPath->reloadData->cellForRowAtIndexPath-> etc..).  Try removing this line and see if this fixes your problems.

2: You don't seem to be re-using cells although one of your comments seemt to imply that you think you are.  I would expect the beginning of the method to start similar to the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        /* Load a custom cell from a NIB
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        */
        // Assume SubUnitCell exists somewhere
        SubUnitCell *cell = [[[SubUnitCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Retrieve config data and configure the cell as required in the code below - real config code needs to be added
    NSNumber *isDone = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    SubUnit *subUnit = (SubUnit*)[mSubUnitsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell setTitle:subUnit.title];

    if([myNotes count] ==0)
    {
        [cell setExer1Done:NO];
        [cell setExer2Done:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"My notes count:--------unitviewcontroller----->%d",[myNotes count]);    
    }

    // All your other configuration code
    .......
    .......
    .......

    return cell; 
}
```

Also please try and post the symbolicated crash log so people can see the exact error and path to the error.

Comment: I went with first option but didn't fix anything. It still give bad_access at viewdidappear method at reload data.

Comment: when i went with second option i.e dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier then cell do not respond to set title methods and other methods etc. Displaying warnings wherever methods called by cell.

Comment: yes, you are right i don't want reuse the cell but if u suggested to go with dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier then i am going for this

Comment: I would definitely use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and now let's fix the setTitle method not responding.  Please post the warnings that are being generated by the compiler (and the static compiler).  Also where is the SubUnitCell being created - from a NIB?

Comment: warning was: "cell may not respond to setTitle. but i resolved that by replacing the line by                                        SubUnitCell *cell = (SubUnitCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        now when i  navigate back to controller then row remain selected from where i push the new controller. i am posting the didSelectRowAtIndex method and SubUnitCell is created programmatically.

Comment: plz tell when u will b available online!!

Comment: I'm getting confused by what issue / error you are having and which code has been replaced.  You need to post a new question with the apropriate code (you might get more than me answering as well).  But check that the SubUnitCell object has a Title property with a setter/getter.